# Sending object from one activity to another

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a activity which takes a list of object and passing to another activty for processing. But I get NPE. This is my code.

```
public class Order implements Parcelable {

public static class OrderProduct {
    private String productId;
    private String qty;

    public OrderProduct(String productId, String qty) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public String getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(String qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "productId: " + productId + "  qty: " + qty;
    }   

}

private String  customerId;
private Map<String, OrderProduct> products;
private OrderProduct product;

public Order(String customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
    products = new HashMap<String, OrderProduct>();
}

public Order(Parcel in)
{
    product.productId = in.readString();
    product.qty = in.readString();
}

public void setProduct(String productId, String qty) {
    product = products.get(productId);
    if (product == null) {
        product = new OrderProduct(productId, qty);
    }
    else {
        product.setQty(qty);
    }
    products.put(productId, product);
}

public Collection<OrderProduct> getProducts() {
    return products.values();
}

public String getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("Order: customerId: " + customerId + " { ");
    for (OrderProduct product : products.values()) {
        sb.append(" { ").append(product.toString()).append(" } ");
    }
    sb.append(" } ");
    return sb.toString();
}


@Override
public int describeContents()
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dest.writeString(product.getProductId());
    dest.writeString(product.qty);
}

public static final Order.Creator<Order> CREATOR = new Order.Creator<Order>() { 
    public Order createFromParcel(Parcel in) { 
        return new Order(in); 
    } 

    public Order[] newArray(int size) { 
        return new Order[size]; 
    } 
};  


}
```

#############################   ACTIVITY 1   ##################

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.send_menu:
            //saveOrder(order);
            showOrderReview();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

##############  ACITIVITY 2

```
public class ReviewOrderActivity extends Activity
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Order myOrderObject = (Order) i.getParcelableExtra("order");
    Collection<Order.OrderProduct> products = myOrderObject.getProducts();
    System.out.println("Orderrrrrrrrrrrr : " + products.size());

    for (Order.OrderProduct product : products){
    Log.d("---", " product.getQty() "+product.getQty()+"  "+product.getProductId());        
}
```

}

Comment: post the NPE call stack and also point it in the code

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pda.kaizen/com.pda.kaizen.activity.ReviewOrderActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.pda.model.Order$OrderProduct.access$0(Order.java:13)
at com.pda.model.Order.<init>(Order.java:51)
at com.pda.model.Order$1.createFromParcel(Order.java:102)
at com.pda.model.Order$1.createFromParcel(Order.java:1)
at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2103
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1965
at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226
at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your LogCat, this is the best that stands out:

```
public Order(Parcel in) {
    product.productId = in.readString();
    product.qty = in.readString();
}
```

When this constructor is called, `product` is null. Additionally, in this constructor, `products` is not defined. Instead, do:

```
public Order(Parcel in) {
    String productId = in.readString();
    String qty = in.readString();
    product = new OrderProduct(productId, qty);
    products = new HashMap<String, OrderProduct>();
}
```

Comment: 07-24 13:49:44.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 13:49:44.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pda.kaizen/com.pda.kaizen.activity.ReviewOrderActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 13:49:44.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):  at com.pda.model.Order$1.createFromParcel(Order.java:102)
07-24 13:49:44.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):  at com.pda.model.Order$1.createFromParcel(Order.java:1)

Comment: you answer was helpful to get rid of the error but in the ReviewOrder activity i get the list size 0 even though i had one order in it.

Comment: Are you sure `setProduct` is called?

Comment: thanks for your feedback. Can you please elaborate more on your comment

Comment: The method `setProduct` is where you add the Order to `products`. If `setProduct` is never called, there will never be any Orders in that list.

Comment: In the Activity1 it prints out the values stored in the order object,but does not do when i print in in the Activity2             `private void showOrderReview()
 {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Intent i = new Intent(this, ReviewOrderActivity.class);
  i.putExtra("order",order);
  Collection<Order.OrderProduct> products = order.getProducts();
  System.out.println("OrderActivity : " + products.size());
  
  for (Order.OrderProduct product : products){
   Log.d("---", "OrderActivity product.getQty() "+product.getQty()+"  "+product.getProductId());
   
  }
  startActivity(i); 
 }`

Comment: one question, in my Activity1 i.e OrderActivity, i am creating an instacne of Order like this `order = new Order(Integer.toString(customerId));`.is it correct or I need to call the `public Order(Parcel in)` constr

Comment: The `Parcel` constructor is only called by the `Parcelable` interface and shouldn't be called by you. For the reason your products list is empty in `Activity2`, it's because that list is not parceled. If you need further guidance on this, start a new question with your code and detailed problem; exchanging code by comment is impossible.

Comment: I have added a new question, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839331/passing-object-between-activity-contains-null]