# Passing Object between Activity contains NULL

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 2 activity(Order and OrderReview) from which I am sending object from OrderActivity to OrderReviewActivity. The object is NULL when i retrieve it in the OrderReview activity.

**Order Activity**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.send_menu:                
            showOrderReview();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

private void showOrderReview()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ReviewOrderActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("order",order);
    Collection<Order.OrderProduct> products = order.getProducts();
    System.out.println("OrderActivity : " + products.size());

    for (Order.OrderProduct product : products){
        Log.d("---", "OrderActivity product.getQty() "+product.getQty()+"  "+product.getProductId());

    }
    startActivity(i); 
}
```

**OrderReviewActivity**

```
public class ReviewOrderActivity extends Activity
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.orderreview);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Order myOrderObject = (Order) i.getParcelableExtra("order");
    Collection<Order.OrderProduct> products = myOrderObject.getProducts();
    System.out.println("Orderrrrrrrrrrrr : " + products.size());

    for (Order.OrderProduct product : products){
        Log.d("---", " product.getQty() "+product.getQty()+"  "+product.getProductId());

    }       
}
}
```

**Order.java**

```
public class Order implements Parcelable {

public static class OrderProduct {
    private String productId;
    private String qty;

    public OrderProduct(String productId, String qty) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public String getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(String qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "productId: " + productId + "  qty: " + qty;
    }   

}

private String  customerId;
private Map<String, OrderProduct> products;
private OrderProduct product;

public Order(String customerId) {
    Log.v("TAG", "Order constr 1");
    this.customerId = customerId;
    products = new HashMap<String, OrderProduct>();
}

public Order(Parcel in)
{
    Log.v("TAG", "ParcelData(Parcel source): time to put back parcel data");
    String productId = in.readString(); 
    String qty = in.readString(); 
    Log.v("TAG", productId +" qty: "+qty);
    product = new OrderProduct(productId, qty); 
    products = new HashMap<String, OrderProduct>();
}

public void setProduct(String productId, String qty) {
    product = products.get(productId);
    if (product == null) {
        product = new OrderProduct(productId, qty);
    }
    else {
        product.setQty(qty);
    }
    products.put(productId, product);
}

public Collection<OrderProduct> getProducts() {
    return products.values();
}

public String getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("Order: customerId: " + customerId + " { ");
    for (OrderProduct product : products.values()) {
        sb.append(" { ").append(product.toString()).append(" } ");
    }
    sb.append(" } ");
    return sb.toString();
}


@Override
public int describeContents()
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("INSIDE product.getProductId()" +product.getProductId());
    dest.writeString(product.getProductId());
    System.out.println("INSIDE product.getQty()" +product.getQty());
    dest.writeString(product.getQty());
}

public static final Order.Creator<Order> CREATOR = new Order.Creator<Order>() { 
    public Order createFromParcel(Parcel in) { 
        return new Order(in); 
    } 

    public Order[] newArray(int size) { 
        return new Order[size]; 
    } 
};
```

}

Comment: i think, you have to use i.putExtra("order",order); just before the startActivity(i). because you are putting data into order object after putting it into putExtra. Try this and let me know.

Comment: @nick Actually, the extras can be added at any point as long as the `Intent` is not modified (removing the extras) before it is sent.

Comment: @Eric Thanks. Actually i was not aware of this.

Comment: I agree with Eric's feedback,it will not make a differnce as long as my intent is not changed

Comment: @ZAJ Is `myOrderObject` the object that is `null`? Or is `myOrderObject.getProducts()` `null`?

Comment: @Eric yes it is. I am doing printing out the object in the constr of Order.java and it has the ojbect sotred in it. `public Order(Parcel in)
 {
  Log.v("TAG", "ParcelData(Parcel source): time to put back parcel data");
  String productId = in.readString(); 
     String qty = in.readString(); 
     Log.v("TAG", productId +" qty: "+qty);
     product = new OrderProduct(productId, qty); 
     Log.v("TAG", product.getProductId() +"  qty  "+product.getQty());
     products = new HashMap<String, OrderProduct>();
 }`

Comment: @Eric just a wild guess..do i have to make OrderProduct class which is an inner class in Order also implement Parcelable. The code for that class is above in my question

Comment: @Eric myOrderObject.getProducts() null? is null.how can i check if the myOrderObject is NULL

Comment: @ZAJ No, because the `OrderProduct` is created using the ID and quantity. Also you can check if it's null using `if (myOrderObject == null) Log.i("---", "myOrderObject is null");`.

Comment: I added some code to check 
`Intent i = getIntent();
Order myOrderObject = (Order) i.getParcelableExtra("order");
if (myOrderObject == null)
{
 Log.i("---", "myOrderObject is null");
}
else
{
 Log.i("---", "myOrderObject is NOT null");
 Log.i("---", myOrderObject.toString());
 System.out.println(" dddd   "+ myOrderObject.describeContents());
  }`
**and the outout is this**

_myOrderObject is NOT null

Order: customerId: null {  } 
System.out(2855):  dddd   0
_

Comment: what is the log and sysout displaying in showOrderReview() ? are you sure that the products.size > 0 ?? because from the about output, it says that customerId is null and products object size is 0

Comment: @Siva Kumar this is the output to that method
 OrderActivity : 1
 OrderActivity product.getQty() 70  158

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using  i.getParcelableExtra("order"), use i.getSerializableExtra("order"). Hope it works

Comment: these are two different things and i am not using Serializable in my code

Comment: if you just want the object value to be sent to another activity, this would work, as you said that the object in another activity is getting NULL

Comment: yes but according to the Android doc using Seriazable is not recommended and they recommend to use Parcelable.correct me if i have understood it wrong